# Change placement of bottom sheet in Landscape: "Side sheet"

Tags: android, landscape-portrait, bottom-sheet

This is an extension of the questions asked here:

[How to get bottomSheet to open from the top?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39510205/how-to-get-bottomsheet-to-open-from-the-top)

[Android “Top Sheet” equivalent of “Bottom Sheet”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39088269/android-top-sheet-equivalent-of-bottom-sheet)

of course "Bottom Sheet" is called like that for a reason, because you can swipe it from the Bottom.

I found out in my design, that this works very well in portrait mode (Image 1 and 2) but in landscape mode I would like to make better use (more visibility) of the "Main area" (Image 3 ).
For this reason I would like to have a "Side sheet", kind of like a navigation drawer (image 4).

[image]

Till now I am not able to find a solution or alternative so any help is welcome!

---

Below the a basic code that demonstates the problem in Landscape mode

**Main Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container_main"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <!-- Main Content -->
    <include layout="@layout/content_main"
        />

    <!-- Bottom Sheet Content -->
    <include layout="@layout/content_bottom_sheet"
        />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**content_main.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.6">
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**content_bottom_sheet.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:class="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/bottomSheetLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="50dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.9"
        android:weightSum="4">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/category0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#BB45BBEC"
            android:onClick="jumpto0"
            />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/category1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#AAA"
            android:onClick="jumpto1"
            />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/category2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FFEF53"
            android:onClick="jumpto2"
            />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/category3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FFF50E0E"
            android:onClick="jumptp3"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.2">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/bottom1"
            android:layout_width="98dp"
            android:layout_height="62dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="#FFF50E0E"
            />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/bottom2"
            android:layout_width="98dp"
            android:layout_height="62dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="#FFF5"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Perhaps you could add the code you have tried already since this is a programming Q&A website?

Comment: Example code added.

Comment: A bit late but did you manage to obtain what you wanted, as in picture 4?

Comment: Unfortunaly not. I think you might have to change the default code of the CoordinatorLayout widget.
I am still very interested for a solution thought.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you can use a [RightSheetBehavior](https://github.com/OKatrych/RightSheetBehavior). But firstly, you should handle  orientation changes and replace a behavior according to orientation.

Comment: Sorry for the super late reply.
My app is long finished cannot test this but it look promising.
If I have the chance I will let you know but thank for the answer, it might still help others.